# scanf comma seperated with no spaces mixed numbers and strings

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to parse out values from a at modem response and I have not found a way for the final integer value to be scanned out following the string. What makes this more complicated is all the values are variable length, the only possible separator is the `,` character. I also cannot use `strtok` because im on a multithreaded embedded system and another thread already uses strtok.

What sscanf formatter will allow me to parse all 4 values only splitting on `,`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *source = "+UUBTGRW:0,52,0100,1";

    int one, two, four;
    char string[100];

    int count = sscanf(source, "+UUBTGRW:%u,%u,%[^,]s%u", &one, &two, string, &four);

    printf("Source string: %s\n", source);
    printf("Count: %u , One: %u , Two: %u , String: %s , Four: %u \n", count, one, two, string, four);

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
Source string: +UUBTGRW:0,52,0100,1
Count: 3 , One: 0 , Two: 52 , String: 0100 , Four: 0
```

Desired output would be:

```
Count: 4 , One: 0 , Two: 52 , String: 0100 , Four: 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't the format string be `"+UUBTGRW:%u,%u,%[^,],%u"` (note the additional comma)

Comment: You can use `strtok_r()` instead of `strtok()`.  As your thread using `strtok()` ought also to do.  `strtok_r()` can be used safely by multiple concurrent threads.

Comment: Ctx wins! that `"+UUBTGRW:%u,%u,%[^,],%u"` works. Thanks so much.

Comment: @peisenhower No, you win, getting work done for free ;)

Comment: I think of it as time saving. Thanks again.

Comment: Do not post answers in the question.  You can post an answer below.